# json-server can we use other key instead of id for post and put request

Tags: npm, json-server

**I have fake api for testing in frontend side.**

i have seen that id is required to put or post your data in json-server package, my question is can i use different key instead of id for ex.

```
{
  id: 1, ---> i want to change this with my custom id
  name: 'Test'
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Let's see CLI options of **json-server** package:
`$ json-server -h`

```
...
--id, -i   Set database id property (e.g. _id)   [default: "id"]
...
```

Let's try to start json-server with new id called '**customId**' (for example):
`json-server --id customId testDb.json`

Structure of **testDb.json** file: `$ cat testDb.json`

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "customId": 1,
      "description": "somedescription",
      "body": "sometext"
    }
  ]
}
```

Make a simple POST request via `$.ajax` function (or via Fiddler/Postman/etc.). `Content-type` of request should be set to `application/json` - explanation may be found on this project's github page:

> A POST, PUT or PATCH request should include a Content-Type: application/json header to use the JSON in the request body. Otherwise it will result in a 200 OK but without changes being made to the data.

So... Make a request from Browser:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/messages/',
  data: {body: 'body', description: 'description'},
  success: resp => console.log(resp),
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Go to `testDb` and see the results. New chunk added. id automatically added with the desired name specified in `--id key` of console cmd.

`{
  "body": "body",
  "description": "description",
  "customId": 12
}`

Voila!

Comment: Can we update another property as auto increment like id?
'id':1,
'layerNumber':1
Can we updated layerNumber with id's value on save?

Comment: Does the --id attribute set it for every table? Is it possible to have it per table?

Answer (score 5):

I've came up with using custom routes in cases where I need custom id:
json-server --watch db.json --routes routes.json

routes.json:

```
{ "/customIDroute/:cusomID" : "/customIDroute?cusomID=:cusomID" }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `{"/route/:id": "/route?customId=:id"}`. At least that worked for me

Comment: Yup, that's the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately that will return an array

Comment: it is however possible to return a single object through middlewares code, but I do have problems with POST and PATCH with this approach

Answer (score 2):

If you start your server using a `server.js` file (read more about it [in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#module)), you can define custom ID routes in `server.js` like this

```js
// server.js
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

server.use(middlewares)

// custom routes
server.use(jsonServer.rewriter({
  "/route/:id": "/route?customId=:id"
}))

server.use(router)
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running')
})
```

And you would start your server with command:

```
node server.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Internaly `getById` from [lodash-id](https://github.com/typicode/lodash-id) is used.

If you use file-based server version the equivalent to cli --id, -i
is `router.db._.id = "customId";`

If you want to do per resource, you can do it with a middleware like this (put before others):

```js
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url.includes("/resourceName/")) {
        router.db._.id = "code";
    } else {
        router.db._.id = "pk";
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: If you want to do per resource , this wont't work this way you must add  next() after the if statement .